# Is there a way to make a responsive layer node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, sknode

I'm new to SpriteKit, I've searched for the answer to this but can't seem to find one.

**Is there a way to make a node that will expand to fit whatever device you're on?**

Right now I'm creating layers with either a concrete dimension or a ratio. What I'd like to do is create an expandable rectangle, attach a physics body to it and have that be the boundary for my game.

what I'm currently doing:

gamescene.swift

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0 / 9.0
        let maxAspectRatioheight = size.width / maxAspectRatio
        let playableMargin: CGFloat = (size.height - maxAspectRatioheight) / 2
        let playableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: size.height - playableMargin * 2)

        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: playableRect)
}
```

but I've experimented with using a background as well:

```
// declared with the other fields outside method
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

//inside didMoveToView
    let bounds = SKNode()
        bounds.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:
            CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
            width: background.size.width,
            height: background.size.height))
        bounds.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boundary
        bounds.physicsBody!.friction = 0
        worldNode.addChild(bounds)
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Everything in iOS is fixed. You need to manually set all widths in accordance with screen size. Your skView object, view, contains a frame object. Within that is a CGSize which will tell you how big the screen is. You can size all of your nodes accordingly.

Comment: maybe SKScene scaleMode is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks @PaddyCollins i had a feeling this would be the answer, thanks for your response. I'll read more about CGSize